# Sound Request- Baseball Bat hit

Tags: design, foley

Hey guys,

Currently working on a student's Baseball short and I'm looking for a sound effect of a baseball bat hitting a baseball. All of the ones I possess don't contain that iconic snap and thwack. Any leads, or if someone has an effect they would be willing to share, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was a fun challenge - I tried to quickly create a baseball smack - but I could only use elements from my own library. Here's what I came up with - you're welcome to it if it does the job.

http://www.squeakyfish.com.au/shared/wooden%20baseball%20bat%20-%20smack%20hit.wav

Oh, though I didn't know if the bat was metal or wood. If this sound is in the ballpark for what you need, I can replace the wood smack elements with metal if need be. You may find that you'll want to add a gunshot to this (or maybe even part of an explosion sound) to go for a real dramatic smack.

Comment: I'm going to download this and test it with the picture. Like what you did with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got some stuff I recorded during batting practice at the ballpark at arlington.  pint me rcoronado1 at gmail

Comment: @Rene Emailing you now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked freesound.org? Tons of samples available for commercial and non-commercial use.

http://www.freesound.org/

I wasn't able to listen to this on this machine, but I did find the following link:

http://www.freesound.org/people/CGEffex/sounds/93136/#